# how to use tags or symbols in latex?

Tags: spacing, macros

I am writing report using Latex software but I got stuck while using tags.

consider  a statement( for example):

> for any A ∈ Γ, B ⊆ A implies B ∈ Γ. The traditional (t, n) threshold secret sharing [3 - 9] is a special case of general secret sharing.Their qualified subsets are those that have at least a certain, per-determined number of participants.

And my latex code :

```
for any A \in T, B  \subseteq A implies B \in T.The traditional (t, n) 
threshold secret sharing [3 - 9] may be a special case of general secret sharing.
Their qualified subsets area unit those who have a minimum of an exact, 
pre-determined variety of participants.
```

The output generated in the PDF look like:

> for any A ∈ T;B ⊆ AimpliesB ∈ T.Thetraditional(t,n)thresholdsecretsharing[ 3-9]maybeaspecialcaseofgeneralsecretsharing:T heirqdeterminedvarietyofparticipants.

My questions is when I am using some tags, after using tags text occurring after that tag is  displayed without space between them as you can see in the latex output above.

I have referred latex pdf also but I am not getting my answer.
so please suggest to me some way so I can display my text in original form as you can see in example statement.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

TeX must give you errors like

```
Missing $ inserted. [for any A \in]
```

which it tries to ignore and compiles the document anyway. This is because `\in` belongs to the math mode, so TeX enables it, and applies it until the end of the document. In math mode spaces between characters are ignored (I'm simplifying here a little, but it does not matter for this question), so all the text after the first `\in` lacks spaces.

To have your desired output, you must enable and disable the math mode explicitly (inline math is written between dollar signs):

```
for any $A \in T$, $B \subseteq A$ implies $B \in T$. The traditional 
$(t, n)$ threshold secret sharing [3 - 9] may be a special case of general 
secret sharing. Their qualified subsets area unit those who have a minimum 
of an exact, pre-determined variety of participants.
```

For the future: questions about TeX belong on [TeX.SE](http://tex.stackexchange.com).